# ActionController :: UnknownFormat when I try to delete in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord, coffeescript

I have the following code and I want to create a modal confirmation to delete a campaign in my app.

The part of my view where the button is is:

```
<div class="col s6 m3 offset-m3 l2 offset-l4">
  <%= form_for @campaign, method: 'delete', html: {class: 'remove_campaign'} do |f| %>
    <button type='submit' class="waves-effect waves-light btn grey">Remover</button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I created `_remove_member_modal.html.erb` as follows:

```
<div id="remove_campaign_modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="row">
      <%= form_for(@campaign, :method => :delete, class: "col s12 remove_campaing_form") do %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <h4>Remover Campanha</h4>
            <p>Você quer mesmo deletar a campanha?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <%= submit_tag("Remover", class: "btn red right") %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have `campaigns.coffee` where I have the following code:

```
$('.remove_campaign').click (e) ->
  $('#remove_campaign_modal').modal('open')
  $('.remove_campaign_form').attr('action', 'campaigns/' + e.target.id)
  return false

  $('.remove_campaign_form').on 'submit', (e) ->
    $.ajax e.target.action,
      type: 'DELETE'
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {}
      success: (data, text, jqXHR) ->
        $(location).attr('href','/campaigns');
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        Materialize.toast('Problema na remoção da Campanha', 4000, 'red')
  return false
```

Inside the modal when I click the delete button I get the following error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in CampaignsController#destroy

My controller's `destroy` action is as follows:

```
def destroy
  @campaign.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: true }
  end
end
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: If you submit the `.remove_campaign_form` but don't prevent the default behavior, it'll be processed as a HTML request, and you'll have to respond in html format too. Can you check one of those two things?

Comment: If i use format.html { redirect_to campaigns_path } I get a correct result without error, why does not it work with render json: true?

Comment: Because you're doing a HTML request, try adding `e.preventDefault()` before `$.ajax e.target.action` and removing the respond in html format.

Comment: I think as you're using AJAX you don't need the forms, you can pass the url and data manually in the ajax function.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: as SebastianPalma told the issue is you are making a `.html` request to server. Instead you can try with by appending `.json` at the end of the url. which works for sure. 'http:/something/somecontroller/:id.json'